# How long do i have to wait for a NHibernate version which supports ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, nhibernate

I'm developing with WPF and NHibernate. Best thing to bind Collections to WPF-Lists is the ObservableCollection. NHibernate does not support this; deals only with IList.

How long do I have to wait for a NHibernate version which supports ObservableCollection?

Comment: yes! A question concerning future releases of NHibernate.

Comment: Dear Sleiman, i really like to know if someone has any news about the plans of future releases of NHibernate. What is planned? Is the development continuing? Do i need an internal framework? Do i have to work around it?

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of answer i wanted to read. :D

Comment: Why don't you post the question on the [NHibernate Forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewforum.php?f=25).They would be a little closer to being able to answer your question. and check out their [Roadmap](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateRoadmap)

Comment: Thanks Mark for the links! That helps!

Comment: Since it's an open source project you could add it yourself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate project is a mature and open-source project and many big projects depend on it, so its development will never stop. Logically NHibernate will not support ObservableCollection. (I am not sure).NHibernate data-structures are very abstract so it fits with every apllication

Answer (score 3):

It supports ObservableCollections. Please check http://code.google.com/p/unhaddins/

In here, the NHibernate community puts everything that is out of the scope of the NHibernate core (It's unofficial but maintained by the same community).

Hope it helps.

Comment: So, the actual answer to the question: You have to wait nothing.

Comment: all your base are belong to us